# Middle static Classes without interface in typescript

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, typescript-generics, entity-component-system

I am currently exploring an alternative to an approach that previously worked but has some complexities in JavaScript that I would like to avoid.

So, I've reconsidered the TypeScript layer a bit, and I've come up with something very close to what I want.

The only issue is, I have an error that I can't get rid of **without using ts-ignore**.

Does anyone know how I could resolve it without breaking the following design?

- I want to avoid implementations and code duplication, so TypeScript needs to infer types from the JavaScript layer, **but I can afford some ts hack and complexity in the abstractions classes**
- proto need look like this in js: `(System* => _SystemGameMiddle => SystemGameMiddle => _System => System)`
- i can add type complexity in in `SystemGameMiddle` or `System` but not in `System*`
- `system.test` should expose all components injected to classes type.

```
type Constructor<T> = new ( ...args: never ) => T;
type ComponentType<T extends Component=Component> = Constructor<T>


// components
abstract class Component {}
class ComponentA extends Component { #id = Symbol() }
class ComponentB extends Component { #id = Symbol() }
class ComponentC extends Component { #id = Symbol() }

// systems
abstract class System<R extends ComponentType[]=ComponentType[]> {
    static config<
        const R extends ComponentType[],
    >(
        config: R
    ) {
        abstract class __System<RR extends ComponentType[]=R> extends this<RR|R> {}
        return __System;
    }

    declare test1: R;
    declare test2: R[number];
    declare test3: <T extends R[number]>() => T;

    public update() {
        this.test1;
    }
}

// try adding any "middleware" class between System and final systemA
//// @ts-ignore - this is not really a solution to use  @ts-ignore
abstract class SystemGameMiddle<R extends ComponentType[]=ComponentType[]> extends System.config(
    [ComponentA] // this middleware will intercept constructor to also add and make avaible ComponentA
)<R> {
    static override config<
        const R extends ComponentType[],
    >(
        config: R
    ) {
        abstract class _SystemGameMiddle<RR extends ComponentType[]=R> extends this<RR|R> {}

        // this will work for ts side, but add complexity on js side because need add static field to keep track of the original config and we also lost the extends of SystemGameMiddle
        // abstract class _SystemGameMiddle<RR extends ComponentType[]=R> extends super.config( config )<RR|R> {}
        return _SystemGameMiddle;
    }

    override update() {
        this.test1;
        this.test2;
        this.test3();
    }
}

// for the hight level, i hould not have typescript complexity, ts should be almost automaticly deduce the type with ths js side injected in static class field
export class System1 extends SystemGameMiddle.config(
    [ComponentB]
) {
}

export class System2 extends SystemGameMiddle.config(
    [ComponentB, ComponentC]
) {
}

// TEST:::
// js: proto should be (System1 => _SystemGameMiddle => SystemGameMiddle => __System => System)
declare const system1:System1;
system1.test1; //ts: expected: [] | [typeof ComponentA] | [typeof ComponentB]
system1.test2; //ts: expected:  typeof ComponentA | typeof ComponentB
system1.test3(); //ts: expected:  typeof ComponentA | typeof ComponentB
// js: proto should be (System2 => _SystemGameMiddle => SystemGameMiddle => __System => System)
declare const system2:System2;
system2.test1; // ts: expected:  [] | [typeof ComponentA] | [typeof ComponentB, typeof ComponentC]
system2.test2; //ts: expected:  typeof ComponentA | typeof ComponentB | typeof ComponentC
system2.test3(); //ts: expected:  typeof ComponentA | typeof ComponentB | typeof ComponentC

type SystemWith<
    R extends ComponentType,
> = System & { test3<T extends R>( ): T}; // with implements

function useSystem1( system:System ) {
    system.test1;
    system.test3;
}
function useSystem2( system:SystemGameMiddle ) {
    system.test1;
    system.test3;
}
function useSystem3( system:SystemWith<typeof ComponentB> ) {
    system.test1;
    system.test3();
}
useSystem1( system1 );
useSystem2( system1 );
useSystem3( system1 );
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#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-2dVpiNvdAGZeJoZaLXj6-cEA5SxOQJNJoRBMMEogiYJgIPo4VAFsyofLFUx3fbTelzZ5ALwbgBZd23oMAwVj6fTVJAcNtIVsAInktX0UVo7Cg-c52QTIBoUBUjWNl17dVRSFYURgZ2e+WAnk8MAAAgEALRopD4WAn20KoyKqgIJLajdRVusLdtTDw5C2hC5lCwEep7npeQShOykQPEY-KXAA4qw8hQAAssOo5vB8hLAv4oIAkCfSqDh-zSiKowwfITA0miVJQr8RL+Pk-wwAeZZGEOHajjQ44wDQ1RRJuXZ6Og2BQBA9zIGETj4L+bZRCgf7tnUrAjDA8isAA1rArD8Kw1RZnIWGqLuIhvBC0KwvCiIIII6DoLUsCUei1LiUkwoEl84pgv85JQpSTlILS9KMikmJsuEkHLDyZHwYhKHsVAyoYe52EkpKxFuTeirKmqELmiyzG3txvGbjQ+BqTAyJSQEW52aSMDBF+bYdkiiijto1TgDAP4AFZGCgdl1VarCYABfBQIpTXmTmqJQFEdR4DAGkic2ERlQgyI3rA+Bol2G5Iv5aIrtxmmyX+UQIGgG2JZ161RQhyGoVAmIHqFHJQZFS7yNF91xQl0aYfhagpeQ6p-b1eZCBRKJUXttKiFl6ppJi2q6vq73PF9sUjlA1ZuFCVlCLZlq5vmhbFpiLEVlADqmqWt6U2gHo0xT4YdDjtZeBVwjyrACocHKSSjoIUS1dUMByggmCzQ+SRylpbqyCg2C2aJzUQK17VgLVVUoOLkt1AmMnyOdSRDXgqkWa+MCWvoOBunK8vQIV8o3kYPXVUTXZdVaeh1F2W4gHCOZvdNs3ADoSjoPcEVkfaV23TFD2Q-tHDUbRBkgP0-zAEywDmuH+BR1yZEenHH0Y4nDmp3Rqj9LV1drFnOfszARAAKINEQ3Bd3uXg9bwEDoI+f46xLUsG-QMfiGjArl3FU-x99WNT7yZHzx9IjAC6Ib2c5W4fY6MfSNuAr2vTIBVkx7gBLw4fe2NvAAjAKowL84DQGtYr0Yxz+v7IH-15nYAx9Lin3dIzS+18ijQFwPfGAto-7rXroUZ+b8oD-3Tv0IB+8z5hlZhAngUC776F4PA9+iD07INIWg8hANMEHj7jAAeQ8ty6zHrACeH0S4pmnnBO6mNRxr3Rnwh6y8jTPEEQKDeW8uLYgusA+QXpi5H04WfC+zECG3xgcQuBj8f6oPQQDBiT8X76JoasWuVCDGrDgFneRHoz7gM8JAzRPsSGmM-oZYx7iAFeIQR4tYWDnj2JZiISQ+Cb7aGga4uB3iKG+LIf4wYKC-H1zgG4VBi5ngAHV2pygxFCVymx66gnJLYTJAoYAADIKjhijCRIwUpGAiF4EQVIYSDw8WdtUFqlx-CBGAMiTASBcDVB-MNKAMdGDyO4KvHOMIPqqNNPInB0h0iDOGd+A04zi5TI+jMsuwi55zOWZWJZCzwyrIGUMkZYyAJkVwXvZ4+zsm5IILE2hZBjnnKpufM5zwcGs1zsAbZ+9dnPFjqE4FdzOFgpPqIaQILngPPkRC6QQA)

Comment: This is quite complicated, and it looks like you're hoping that the compiler will give `__System` a type sufficiently strong to keep track of what you're doing.  Could you manually give `__System` a type annotation that represents your intent as closely as possible? I tried to do so [over here](https://tsplay.dev/WGb80m) and it seems to be quite similar to what you're doing, but the error goes away. Does that meet your needs? Also I don't understand why you expect `[] | ` in there, when you don't mention `[]` anywhere in the code. ... Could you possibly whittle this down to a [mre]?

Comment: ho!, You are absolutely right. I feel bad for confusing you with that `[]`. 
It was an old test when cleaning up my example to present it here. I apologize for confusion.
Your approach is truly clever! i like it, and yes, I think you've succeeded in unblocking me. I will explore it in a my more complex design by tomorrow and verify that all additional security measures are functioning correctly. Thank you immensely for your time for help people. I'll come back with confirmation as soon as possible.

Comment: Okay, I'll check back and if it helps you I'll write up an answer with the suggestion.

Comment: @jcalz oki all test are passed thank you so much, I tweaked SystemCtor to allow me to extend it across multiple hypothetical middleware and that works too, I guess I can't make it more generic at this point and have to duplicate it for every abstract class I want add.

`tinyurl.com/mryehuxp`

Otherwise your approach suits me and answers my question perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I'm seeing is that you are expecting a bit too much of TypeScript's inference abilities. Inside the static `config()` method you return a locally declared `class` named `__System`. You want that that class to have a strong type that keeps track of the `R` type argument.  But it doesn't seem to do so. It's hard to tell *what* it actually is, since the IntelliSense will show you `typeof __System`, which doesn't give any information.

The first step I would take here is to explicitly write out the types you want things to be and see if the compiler can *verify* that your values conform to them, instead of just hoping that they will be *inferred* that way.  Then if things still don't work, at least you can see where they go wrong.

To that end, I'd say that the `__System` class is an [`abstract` class constructor type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#abstract-construct-signatures) which constructs `System` instances, and which has its own `config` method.  By inspection of your code, it looks like this:

```
type SystemCtor<RR extends ComponentType[]> = (
    abstract new <R extends ComponentType[]>() => System<R | RR>
) & {
    config<R extends ComponentType[]>(config: R): SystemCtor<R | RR>
};
```

Notice how `SystemCtor<RR>` is recursively defined, and how each call to `config()` will incorporate `R` and `RR` together in a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  Also I had to make it an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) because there's no way to use `abstract new` inside of the same object type as `config` (see [this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#36392](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/36392#issuecomment-1025807607)).

And now, by inspection, it seems like we want `config()` to return a `SystemCtor<R>`, so let's [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) it as such:

```
abstract class System<R extends ComponentType[] = ComponentType[]> {
    static config<const R extends ComponentType[]>(
        config: R
    ): SystemCtor<R> { // <-- annotated the return type
        abstract class __System<RR extends ComponentType[] = R> extends this<RR | R> { }
        return __System;
    }

}
```

And that compiles without error.  So while the compiler didn't *infer* that dependence on `R`, it's happy enough to allow it to be annotated.

Once we do that things more or less just start working for you:

```
declare const system1: System1;
system1.test1; // [typeof ComponentA] | [typeof ComponentB]
system1.test2; // typeof ComponentA | typeof ComponentB
system1.test3(); // typeof ComponentA | typeof ComponentB

declare const system2: System2;
system2.test1; // [typeof ComponentA] | [typeof ComponentB, typeof ComponentC]
system2.test2; // typeof ComponentA | typeof ComponentB | typeof ComponentC
system2.test3(); // typeof ComponentA | typeof ComponentB | typeof ComponentC
```

---

This may or may not be enough for your particular use case, but the point is that you should take more explicit control over the types if the inferred ones don't meet your needs.  Yes, this can be tedious, since you'll end up writing things that are at least conceptually redundant, but it has the advantage of helping express your actual intent and pinpointing problems.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqAfFALxQIQDuUAFAHSMCGqA5kgFwUQBuEqASjIkCAbgBQoSLDgBbMIggJgBcBEJQIAD2BKAJkhnzFyskYWVlJcvGRosOfMXHiA9K6iY5FpcCTimACMUVCZsTwAbJiRDeGNLYCgAbygAX3FMKJjzE2AAQU0dfVjvXOSoAGIASz0zAGUQWUC4CNohdMzokvjfACFC3QQDHITy6tryBqaWtrSMrO6fZRgB4pHfMZr6xubW9pd3KCQQFAhZf0k1KAbT2RhHPAAlR9WhxdzVSABtAF1rOnEAEggiEwolKDQnq9hnElio1L8iLNSCQbrpZFCAD5QZ5EcRCABkySBXgQADMqqwodpBjDSglPhBEbRSRTWFxHgIuGizvdcFicY88akJAFgmgwZEutcTujqUU3utlIzfmZYR8EX9iYCUExgFVMJ5EGy8KSUDjoe8GZqkUDAazKRygVyZbc+fghdrgeLQuFOtkAPoBnkY56WpXw74-MyemlrYAACyqSCeL2xnpS6UBgNQEGA6FQCCgQZDEkB6SBeggnVzUF0KAAjByy1Wa9B68AAEwcr4IdBNfg-FvVqK1jsAZi4Gjjisevf7gUHSKEKKgYhcgLA6ECEQNUHQYD0eogsySdsTyfoHYbZfSFbFoL9C1d6IA4kxZBAALI1PQRdQvDOdI9MqmpqvSvgqlqQGGCG9AOqwtBAl86oJHk0aHBehiyL+-5UCw0BUFUEQRFAVTKPwmAQGAiRmvY2C4HWcBQEwERIMxTB6LUTBDFAshMAA1tATA8EwVQ7tAqG+Hk+JPCQZ46sAep7nAfCoKgNTQAheB2nRFowRGUEADRAra2YIU6gJCAp3qPrRz7BrKZzvp+P5cf+qbhlJoFRjGJAGVhnnpvJcx2phSaGERJFQFQuACVAZKMX4RyaUZUCBOgiScbUXjyP+WhVKAUCIFAABWhhIJp6XVkw6BINAlAQNxXFHEp+qGhSEARLUOBQEJ1F1r68VwGSdYJtAuCUuRrFGuSlIsbxVDCWxzERHA5qJtABkjS+zkft+uEQGFHgghKT7So5twuQd7kAYBCrAXCUGkLGD0VQe-DwcalK0LNbJQAIqaYhmWY5nmBZFpdb77W5f4QLeG6qfwGlVvuh7Hqe54RVeECNmWgJYTjKCdvjhMTm0CMVociWoGN0BJqwCaJP+fARGlVRQAmcDoN1FBwIkCYie2ahIJgGk0UaeXaIVIBpclSBczztSLixESyOtWWZXIymZCAUBVnoWDtuNdZXERiZjYY5Upaj5GldWui1ORrU61K2Sdd14jaAoqD2dKIYNuGIbXbD-5fXNiHId5wC9D8+LEhW3u4H72Qhp2QdObIIeHeHbJIYCKEQcovRpdHMBx9Z4hUx4BAAKJ1AQHBN+IrajlpiDmsctxNrtsg3uIXfog2RPADeUCHF8UgQDt0foVA2KT2oM9FzHceD2cw8diT48eFPy8gfk8+m5A+9wr0A+Z5vuPAOOFM78f0+jbPR970-K-ny3I4EbNneZ92vckwvrcTsI8x4T1fhGOeC8IHRxLg-U+uRy5APRCAreoh74wJXgUbEmCD79BwUvN+B8YDILOKg6+t8BDoMwoQyBL9aGwPoSfIhcISGXGkCGAA6oVBMOlAT3VpFaSCagTL-BDFAIkKQJzTjejiZcXACBpGoR4c2CYyJS0-MoC4ZJ0AIGwFUEqdUIAB1oOvWQ3JM6Vx1JnUBZYzEj3HBIdIOi9H6kMfVNOpjM4WKujDQ6Vj7HXjsTYicTjxAuP0e44xmdb5mJ8eibhiY8C4LPkQAJITr792sbcBxFMq7iCMSYsxDYqEFI8X-Lx3dSmFJiZUoepSgA)

Comment: it is not sufficient, you are right, I had some small ts utility aside which after testing it does its job correctly and bring me where i want, I have omitted it to keep the example a little more digestible and ludique even if at first glance it does not seem very logical, it makes sense in my current migrations.
Thank you for your precious time, it is always very educational to read you. @+